# How to read/write byte[] into Isolated storage

Tags: windows-phone-7

Can anyone tell me how to read and write byte array into Isolated Storage file in WP7?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`IsolatedStorageFileSystem` has a method for writing byte arrays:

```
public override void Write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count);
```

It can be used as follows:

```
  byte[] myByteArray = ...
  using (var store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
  using (var stream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("filename.txt",
                 FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, store))
  {
      stream.Write(myByteArray, 0, myByteArray.Length);
  }
```

Comment: Can I use IsolatedStorageFile in Windows Forms application for write in a file, and read it later?