# How to save and read a byte[] into a IsolatedStorageFile

Tags: windows-phone-7

i know how to save a string into the `IsolatedStorageFile` but what about a `byte[]` ?
for a string i do:

```
string enc = "myString";
using (var iso = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
{
    using (var stream = iso.OpenFile("fileName", FileMode.Create))
    {
        var writer = new StreamWriter(stream);
        writer.Write(enc);
        writer.Close();
     }
}
```

EDIT: okay i know now how to write, but how to read out the byte[] again?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to read/write byte\[\] into Isolated storage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6420565/how-to-read-write-byte-into-isolated-storage)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `BinaryWriter` instead of `StreamWriter`.

Comment: BinaryReader.ReadBytes(); but i dont know the length

Comment: Write length first, as int (before writing byte array).

Comment: `writer.Write(byteArray.Length); writer.Write(byteArray);` Then you can `reader.ReadBytes(reader.ReadInt32());`

Answer (score 2):

To write a byte array, instead of enclosing your stream in a StreamWriter, use directly `stream.Write`. Or use a BinaryWriter.

For instance:

```
stream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
```

Comment: var binaryArray = new byte[stream.Length]; stream.Read(binaryArray, 0, binaryArray.Length);